# How to Keep radio button aligned horizontally when browser window shrinks with CSS

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have created a form and in this form there are several radio buttons: three for each line, horizontally aligned.

When the browser window shrink these radio buttons wrap so they are not horizontally aligned any more.

The relevant css is:

```
.radio {

  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.radio:nth-child(1) {


}

.radio:nth-child(2) {

}

.radio:nth-child(3) {

 }
```

I need a css only solution to this problem: so far I only found alternative solution (html/css or js) but none of these is purely css.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

dom

Comment: use `media-query` for that

Comment: Please create sample demo in jsfiddle and update your question with it. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @user3130919  please show your full code